# Can I ground a new light to an old metal box via a switch yoke?

Tags: electrical, switch, grounding, old-house, old-work

All of my switches are installed in old metal boxes with no threaded ground screw holes.  The boxes are wired using old cloth BX with no ground wire(grounded via casing).  Some of the BX wire insulation is crumbling near light fixtures, I think due to heat.

As I replace the light fixtures I'd like to replace the BX from light to box with Romex.  The BX that supplies the box is in good shape.  How do I appropriately ground the new fixtures.  There are no threaded holes in the metal boxes.  Grounding to the box via the yoke on new switches will work but I don't think this is proper.  Can I just tap a new 10-32 hole in the box? Should I tear out all of the old bx or maybe just run new ground wires?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think tapping a new hole in the box is far superior to relying on the sometimes wobbly contact between the yoke and the box.

Comment: Another problem with using the switch yoke as part of the ground path is that whenever you pull the switch out for maintenance or analysis, the light is no longer grounded. This could add confusion to the analysis of a failure by some future DIY electrician.

Comment: Another method of grounding to a metal box is the spring clip which holds a ground pigtail hard against the box. https://www.grainger.com/product/2DCN3?cm_mmc=PPC

Comment: @Jim Stewart: If you can find a reference that indicates that the clip is usually acceptable to electrical codes, this should be an answer.

Comment: I am deleting my comment advocating using the mounting tab to ground a switch because of the answers in this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103034/grounding-a-3-switch-metal-device-box. Evidently using the *plain* end tab of a switch for grounding is not allowed for *flush mounted* metal boxes. It is allowed only for surface mounted metal boxes. Devices labelled "self grounding" (with spring loaded contacts) presumably are allowed even on flush mounted metal boxes.

Comment: Concerning grounding in the metal box for the light fixture when you have changed to NM cable from the light fixture box to the switch box from the original BX, I think the prudent course would be to secure the ground wire to the box and leave a free end to connect to a ground wire from the fixture, if any. Do all code approved light fixtures have a grounding wire or do some depend on the mounting hardwared?

Comment: I would hope not, mounting hardware is not reliable unless the flanges land hard metal-metal.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm going to tap new 10-32 holes for proper ground screws.  I think that is the safest bet.